# Extracting user interests from social profiles

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, extract, information-extraction

This is my first time dabbling in NLP so please excuse my ignorance.  I'm looking for a method to extract interests/likes/hobbies from users' social profiles. Here is an example where all the interests/likes/hobbies are in bold:

> "I consider myself a pretty diverse character... I'm a professional
>   **wrestler**, but I'd take a bullet for **Wall•E**. I train like a one-man genocide machine in the **gym**, but I cried at
>   "**Armageddon**." I'll head bang to **AC/DC**, and I'm seriously
>   considering getting a **Legend of Zelda** tattoo. I'm 420-friendly. I
>   like to **party** it up with the frat crowd one night, hang out with
>   my **Burning Man** friends the next, play **Halo** and **World of
>   Warcraft** the next, and jam with friends that aren't any younger than
>   40 the next. My youngest friend is 16, my oldest friend is 66. I'll
>   sing **karaoke** at the bars, and I'm my friends' collective
>   psychiatrist/shoulder."

The profiles are plain text. There are no meta tags or ids associated with any of it, it's just a paragraph of text.

My naiive idea was to take each noun and match it against [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) to see if it's an activity/artist/movie/book etc.  The problem is that although most entities mentioned will be things the user likes, she will also mention things she *doesn't* like and I have no means of distinguishing the 2.

I have 2 questions:

1. What sub field of NLP should I be looking at?  Some googleable algorithms/techniques/authors would be greatly appreciated.
2. How hard is this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, unless using NLP to do this is a particular objective for you, check your problem domain to see if you can avoid it completely.

For instance:

- do these profiles have tags (supplied either by the Site or by the
  user)?
- what does the **Site's API** make available (assuming that's how you    are accessing this data; if you are scraping it, then this doesn't of course apply)? A good example, Facebook. if you read a user's posts,    you'll see words like "wrestler", "karaoke", etc. but if you look at    what fields are exposed via the Graph API, you'll see that these    activities nearly always have an associated FB ID.

I am not a specialist in this field, but I can recommend a couple of resources directed to NLP and which are accessible to the non-specialist or novice. The first is a [text processing API](http://text-processing.com/docs/). This simple web service uses REST and JSON IO. It is free and seems to have a fairly large rate limit.

This API appears to rely heavily on the excellent [Natural Language Tooolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) (NLTK) which is a mature stable library in python, that includes modules directed to the problem in your Question, e.g., Sentiment Analysis, Tagging and Chunk Extraction, etc.

Which particular sub-domain is most relevant to solving the Question in the OP? I don't know, but I suspect there's a module somewhere in the NLTK that does what you need. Finding that module is hopefully just a matter of skimming the [API Documentation](http://nltk.github.com/api/nltk.html) (which is organized by module); reading the [Getting Started](http://www.nltk.org/getting-started) section which contains an excellent survey of NLTK's modules as well as demos for all of each of them.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no tags or api. It's literally paragraphs of text. Thanks for the NLTK tip, I love python.  I'll go poke around.